# Is it possible to add an array to a record in perl?

Tags: perl

I added an array to a record, but I'm having trouble accessing the elements of the array. Here's my code.

```
# Create and initialize an array    
@array = (1, 2, 3);

# Add it to a record
$rec = {
    field1 => 'foo',
    field2 => @array
};
```

I tried to print the contents of the array, but it doesn't work.

```
print $rec->{field2}[0] . "\n";
```

My question is...what is the right way to add an array to a record and then access the elements of the array?

Comment: Note that the Perl terminology is actually "hash" rather than "record"; and a hash is said to have "elements" rather than "fields". (These elements are "values" indexed by "keys".) If you want to be a bit fancier, you can also refer to hashes as "associative arrays", as opposed to "regular arrays" like your `@array`.

Comment: "Associative array" isn't fancier, it's just older. The terminology changed when Perl 5 was released (twenty years ago). If you refer to hashes as associative arrays people will just think your Perl knowledge is horribly out of date :-)

Comment: @DaveCross: "Fancier" might not have been the best word-choice on my part, but it's not just that it's older. For example, `perldata` still explains that Perl has "associative arrays of scalars, known as 'hashes'". Essentially: "hash" refers specifically to associative arrays in Perl, whereas "associative array" is a general term for the (language-agnostic) concept of which hashes are an example. It's like the difference between talking about "local variables" and "variables declared with `my`".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to take a reference to array,

```
$rec = {
    field1 => 'foo',
    field2 => \@array
};
```

otherwise array get flattened into the list

```
$rec = {
    field1 => 'foo',
    field2 => 1,
    2, 3
};
```

You might also want to check [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Comment: + 1. Note that you can get the same effect with an *anonymous* reference: `field2 => [1, 2, 3]`. For a tutorial introduction to references, see [the perlreftut manpage](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can access arraysrefs inside of hashrefs like that:

```
$rec->{field2}->[$i]
```

where $i is the index of the element you want to access.

Greetings Tim

edit: Added full working example

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $ref = {field1 => "test", field2 => [5,6,7,8,9]};

print $ref->{field2}->[0],"\n";
print $ref->{field2}->[1],"\n";
print $ref->{field2}->[2],"\n";
print $ref->{field2}->[3],"\n";
print $ref->{field2}->[4],"\n";
```

which will output:

```
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You are welcome :) Well here is a full example which works fine for me, in the code above you would have to replace $i with 0 or whatever index you want. This is how it works:

    #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $ref = {field1 => "test", field2 => [5,6,7,8,9]};

print $ref->{field2}->[0],"\n";
print $ref->{field2}->[1],"\n";
print $ref->{field2}->[2],"\n";
print $ref->{field2}->[3],"\n";
print $ref->{field2}->[4],"\n";

which produces this output: 
tim@tim-V5-131:~$ perl Desktop/t.pl 
5
6
7
8
9

Comment: well goodbye formatting then... will add the full example to my answer.

Comment: The last `->` is not needed, so `$ref->{field2}[4]` works as well.